# $f(z)={z+i\over z-i}, \quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{i\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)={z+i\over z-i}, \quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{i\}$$

a) is conformal.

b) maps right half plane to upper half.

c) maps unit circle around 0 to imaginary axis.

d) maps circles around 0 of radius greater than 1 to first quadrant.

could any one just confirm me whether $a,b,c$ are correct? I have calculated and thats too long so not feeling to  write here. please pardon me for that. Thank you.

Comment: +4 for a cut and paste yes/no question that the OP "doesn't feel like" writing up his thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

(a) $$f(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}=1+\frac{2i}{z-i}\implies f'(z)=-\frac{2i}{(z-i)^2}\neq 0\;\;,\;\;\forall z\in\Bbb C-\{i\}$$

(b) If $\,z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;x>0\;$ , then

$$f(z)=1+\frac{2i}{z-i}=1+\frac{2i}{x+(y-1)i}=1+\frac{2(y-1)+2xi}{x^2+(y-1)^2}$$

So what is $\;\;$Im$\,(f(z))\;\;$ in this case...?

(c) Look at (b) above and think what happens if $\,|z|=1\iff x^2+y^2=1\;$ ...

(d) Think similarly as in (c)...

Comment: $b$ we can see that real and imaginary part are $>0$ so image lies in upper half plane. $c$ yes when $x^2+y^2=1$ only imaginary part is there in the expression of im(f) so true, for $d$ I saw that in imaginary part there was a term $x\over y-1$ so when $y$ is negative that doesnt lie in first quadrant.